# How can the Symfony's Routes, Controllers, Actions and Views be programmatically processed to produce useful documentation or highlight issues?

Tags: php, symfony

I am maintaining a reasonably complex inherited Symfony 2.8 application, with a significant number of Routes, Controllers, Actions, and Views.  Occasionally, I will find that certain Views or Routes or whatever aren't even used, but it's hard to prove that - I end up doing a lot of searching in my IDE, jumping from a template name to an Action to a routing.yml until I finally hit a dead end and realise I can just delete it (and even then I'm nervous!).

Is there a way that I can usefully inspect the configuration and references between these aspects, programmatically, to give me an accurate overview of how it all hangs together, both to see how it does work, and also which bits I can throw away?

As an example, ending up with something like the below without having to make it manually would be very useful:

```
Route       Action         Template                 Routes Linked
-----       ------         --------                 -------------

main_index  Default:index  Default:index.html.twig  new_item; view_news

etc
```

I realise it's a big ask, especially since some of those links are done in PHP code, but fingers crossed...

Comment: You should be able to grab the output of `php bin/console router:debug` (which lists all routes) and do a recursive grep on your templates (and controllers / whatnot) for each route name shouldn't you?

Comment: If you are using PHPstorm already the Symfony Plugin makes routes clickable in Templates.

Answer (score 0):

I use a technique called a 'tombstones'. In the code that I believe is not being used, I'll log to a file. After a few days or weeks of use, in development and live, I see what got logged, and know that they are being used - the rest may be fair game to delete.

In a development environment, where I am running locally, a hit on a tombstone call is an instant die, so I can remove it. In env=test, I'll log it and consider if the test calling it, is also redundant.

For env=prod, it will just be logged to a file for me to look at later (and probably remove the `tombstone()` call).

Things that are not writing to a log, were not called.

I've also [blogged on the subject of tombstones](https://phpscaling.com/2017/08/28/code-tombstones/), with Symfony-specific code & examples, and a link to the library I use to support it.